# Is it possible to check the progress of running e1071::svm function in R

Tags: r, classification, svm

I am running machine learning approaches with a quite large training set (df of 110000x14). All of the models, that I build have satisfying runtime but SVM with radial kernel from 'e1071' library takes too long.
Is there any way to monitor the progress of the function in realtime to understand, how many iterations are passed?